# Return a generic list to the MVC Controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I have a class that looks like this;

```
public class item
{
    public string Tradingname { get; set; }
}
```

I have a Partial View that inherits from the "item" class;

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<item>" %>

<%= Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Tradingname) %>
```

In my view I create a number of them.  Let's Say 2;

```
<% using (Html.BeginForm())
   { %>
<% Html.RenderPartial("TradingName", new Binding.Models.item()); %><br />
<% Html.RenderPartial("TradingName", new Binding.Models.item()); %><br />

<input type="submit" />

<%} %>
```

Then in my controller I was hoping to be able to write this;

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(List<item> items)
```

or

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index([Bind(Prefix = "Tradingname")]List<item> items)
```

But I can't seem to get any data back from my partial views into my List.  Anyone know how I can get a variable list of data back from a variable set of partialViews?

Comment: What does your TradingName partial view look like?

Comment: exactly as you see above.  It simply, at this point, inherits from the model and has a single textbox in it

Comment: I am sorry, I don't know how I missed that. @Darin's solution will work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend you using editor templates:

Controller:

```
public class HomeController: Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        List<item> model = ...
        return View(model);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(List<item> items)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

and in the view:

```
<% using (Html.BeginForm()) { %>
    <%= Html.EditorForModel();
    <input type="submit" />
<% } %>
```

and finally simply move the partial in `~/Views/Home/EditorTemplates/item.ascx` (name and location are important):

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<item>" %>
<%= Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Tradingname) %><br/>
```