# adding multiple objects to arraylist

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, arraylist

Hi I have a method where I am passing values checkbox from the view to the controller. Below is the controller method.

However, when I try to checkbox 2 values from the data table both will pass as the value and the list will be splitted correctly but when adding to the arraylist, only the last one to be checkbox is sent in. My first value will be overwritten by the last one but my count will remain the same.

any help will be appreciated and please go easy on me as I am new with this.

```
public virtual actionresult value(string value)
{
    var list = value.Split('#');
    if (list != null )
    {
        ArrayList arr = new ArrayList();
        for (int i = 0; i < list.Length; i++)
        {
            foreach (var key in list)
            {
                if (key == null || string.IsNullOrEmpty(key.Trim()))
                {
                    continue;
                }

                var nric = key.Split('|')[0];
                var dob = key.Split('|')[1];

                s.NRIC = nric;
                s.DOB = Convert.ToDateTime(dob);

                arr.Add(s);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is _s_? You don't declare it anywhere and you continue to use the same variable at every loop. Of course your arraylist is filled with the same object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`s` needs to be a new object every time you go through your loop.

```
foreach (var key in list)
{
   // ...
   var s = new MyObject();  // create new object

   s.NRIC = nric;
   s.DOB = Convert.ToDateTime(dob);

   arr.Add(s);
}
```

Because if not, you will add a reference to the same object each time when executing `arr.Add(s)`. So changing the value of this referenced object `s.NRIC = nric;` affect all items of `arr` because each item points to this same object.

Further it seems like your `for loop` is redundant, since `foreach` do the same job iterating through the array `list`.

Answer (score 0):

What is s? You don't declare it anywhere and you continue to use the same variable reference at every loop changing the values but not the reference.

Of course your arraylist is filled with the same object and you end up with copies of the same values on all the items added to the ArrayList.

You need to declare the variable *s* for the exact type that you want to add to your ArrayList and then initialize it with *new* at each loop.

In any case it is a lot better to work with a `List<T>` instead of a typeless ArrayList

```
public virtual ActionResult value(string value)
{
    List<YourClassName> arr = new List<YourClassName>();
    if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(value)
       return View(arr);

    var list = value.Split('#');
    // Not needed 
    // if (list != null )
    // {
    //    for (int i = 0; i < list.Length; i++)
    //    {
            foreach (var key in list)
            {
                // In every loop create a new instance of s of the 
                // exact type for your class 
                YourClassName s = new YourClassName();

                if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(key))
                    continue;

                s.NRIC = key.Split('|')[0];
                s.DOB = Convert.ToDateTime(key.Split('|')[1];);

                arr.Add(s);
            }
    //    }
    // }
    return View(arr);
}
```

I am not an expert in MVC and I suppose that this code is in your Controller and you want to return a generic list as [explained in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5547306/return-a-generic-list-to-the-mvc-controller). Feel free to comment/fix on inexact code for the return type.